# Привязка внешнего стиля к DataGridRow и использование в стиле внешней переменной

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

В проекте есть справочники, вывод осуществляется через DataGrid. Иногда в этих справочниках что-то удаляют, но логика программы их не удаляет совсем, а помечает как удаленные. Простому пользователю нужно отображать просто список элементов справочника, а вот пользователям из группы администраторов нужно отобразить основной список элементов и удаленные. При этом удаленные надо пометить (как вариант цветом). Этот код не работает

Вот код стиля для DataGridRow

```
<style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" x:Key="ReferencesDataGridRow">
 <Style.Triggers>
  <MultiDataTrigger>
   <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Condition Binding="{Binding DataContext.IsAdmin, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}, Mode=FindAncestor}}" Value="false" />
    <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Deleted}" Value="true" />
   </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
   <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
  </MultiDataTrigger>
  <MultiDataTrigger>
   <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Condition Binding="{Binding DataContext.IsAdmin, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}, Mode=FindAncestor}}" Value="true" />
    <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Hidden}" Value="true" />
   </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink" />
  </MultiDataTrigger>
 </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

В разметке UserControl применение стиля приходится задавать через ресурсы UserControl, так как непосредственно в DataGrid установка стиля DataGridRow приводит к ошибке ArgumentNullException

```
<UserControl.Resources>
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ReferencesDataGridRow}" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

DataGrid

```
<DataGrid x:Name="VendorsGrid" ItemSource="{Binding VendorsList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedVendor}">
<DataGrid.Columns>
...
</DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Привязка осуществляется в .cs файле UserControl

```
DataContext=MainWindowViewModel.This.CurrentDocument;
```

ViewModel рассматриваемого UserControl

```
...
public bool IsAdim=>UserConfig.IsAdmin;
public VendorModel SelectedVendor
{
 get=>_selectedVendor;
 set=>Set(ref _selectedVendor,value);
}
public ObservableCollection<VendorModel>VendorList{get;}
...
```

Стиль никак не применяется к DataGrid

Собственно вопрос: что не так с разметкой, почему стиль не хочет применяться к DataGrid?

p.s. метод Set() реализует интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged, который любезно подсказал @VladID

Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В ходе экспериментов выяснил, что применение стиля через DataGrid.RowStyle вполне работает. Может это только у меня так отработало, но результат есть

```
<DataGrid>
 <DataGrid.RowStyle>
  <Style TargetType={x:Type DataGridRow}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ReferenceDataGridRow}" />
 </DataGrid.RowStyle>
...
</DataGrid>
```